# Comparing 2 text files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 text files. I want to compare the 2 text files and return a list that has every line number that is different. Right now, I think my code returns the lines that are different, but how do I return the line number instead?

```
def diff(filename1, filename2):
    with open('./exercise-files/text_a.txt', 'r') as filename1:
        with open('./exercise-files/text_b.txt', 'r') as filename2:
            difference = set(filename1).difference(filename2)

    difference.discard('\n')

    with open('diff.txt', 'w') as file_out:
        for line in difference:
            file_out.write(line)
```

Testing on:

```
diff('./exercise-files/text_a.txt', './exercise-files/text_b.txt') == [3, 4, 6]
diff('./exercise-files/text_a.txt', './exercise-files/text_a.txt') == []
```

Comment: You may want to define a wrapper class W, containing line and lineno, with custom `def __eq__` and `def __hash__` respecting line. Then build a list of instances of W, and compute `difference = set(ws1).difference(ws2)`.

Comment: What should be the expected output if `filename` contains duplicate lines?

Comment: Check out the built-in enumerate function, which gives both an index and the item of the iterable.

Answer (score 1):

```
difference = [
    line_number + 1 for line_number, (line1, line2)
    in enumerate(zip(filename1, filename2))
    if line1 != line2
]
```

`zip` takes two (or more) generators and returns a generator of tuples, where each tuple contains the corresponding entries of each generator. `enumerate` takes this generator and returns a generator of tuples, where the first element is the index and the second the value from the original generator. And it's straightforward from there.

Comment: Your answer is clearly the best approach, but could I suggest starting the numbering from 1, because that accords with what is usually meant by line numbers.

Comment: enumerate takes optional starting argument....  to clean up (albeit marginally):  `enumerate(zip(filename1, filename2), 1)` alleviates the `+1`

Comment: @AirSquid Today I learned, thanks. I still prefer my method for clarity though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which will ignore any surplus lines if one file has more lines than the other. The key is to use `enumerate` when iterating to get the line number as well as the contents. `next` can be used to get a line from the file iterator which is not used directly by the `for` loop.

```
def diff(filename1, filename2):
    difference_line_numbers = []
    with open(filename1, "r") as file1, open(filename2, "r") as file2:
        for line_number, contents1 in enumerate(file1, 1):
            try:
                contents2 = next(file2)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            if contents1 != contents2:
                difference_line_numbers.append(line_number)
    return difference_line_numbers
```

Comment: I'm in two minds whether to delete this answer or not. I'll leave it because it does actually work and might perhaps be instructive, but having seen Thomas's answer, the use of `zip` is so much more tidy and straightforward.